# How to find all files in directory? (HTML JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, file, directory, filesystems

How to find all files in directory? I have HTML page in some directory. Using JavaScript I want to get all existing files in some subdirectory ( get all file names or relative links to them, on a local machine)

Comment: Do you want to get all files or all files that the page links to?

Comment: Is this on the server or on a local machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript which runs at the **client** machine can't access the local disk file system due to security restrictions. Otherwise one would be able to upload files in a hidden form unaskingly using Javascript.

If you like to access the **client's** disk file system, then look for the solution in a different corner: an embedded client application which you serve up from your webpage, like an Applet, Webstart, Silverlight or something like that. If you like to access the **server's** disk file system, then look for the solution in the server side corner using the server side programming language like Java, PHP, etc, whatever your webserver is currently using/supporting.

Comment: @systempuntout: That's a poor MSIE proprietary JS library with too much freedom. It wouldn't work for the majority of the world wide web visitors because they have it disabled/restricted or use a better browser.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have your server setup/defaulted so that you can go to a index-less directory and be presented with a list of files and directories that reside in that directory then that information isn't public.

You might want to try writing a short server-side script to retrieve a list of the files in your directory and make an AJAX call to it?